# Determine if emacs knows the mode for a file

Tags: major-mode

I'd like to add another system to set the major modes of file visiting buffers. To do so, I need to know if any of the existing major mode setting systems know how to set the mode, and do my thing only when they do not.

How can I tell if Emacs already knows how to set the mode for a given buffer?

Comment: Inasmuch as the `major-mode` is generally set by the time the `find-file-hook` runs, how about something unsophisticated that determines whether the ultimate mode is `fundamental-mode` or otherwise?:  `(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (if (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode) (message "Fundamental-Mode") (message "%s" major-mode))))`

Comment: @lawlist sorry, I forgot to mention that that's the one thing I can't do. It relies on my manually setting the major mode and so uses `change-major-mode-hook` which fires after the mode is enabled, so I can't just check the current mode.

Comment: The `hack-local-variables-hook` may run even later in time than `change-major-mode-hook`, so perhaps the same concept would work with the H.L.V.H. as outlined in the above-comment?  What I'm trying to do as avoid checking the `auto-mode-alist` and the directory and file local variables.

Comment: @lawlist I'm not sure I follow. `change-major-mode-hook` is already too late, so it doesn't sound like the `hack-local-variables-hook` would help. I know, you definitely don't want to check `auto-mode-alist` and `magic-mode-alis` and `interpreter-mode-alist`, not to mention the file and directory local variables manually. That would be a huge headache.

Comment: My idea was to find the latest moment in time to see whether a file-visiting-buffer was in `fundamental-mode` and then we would know "if any of the existing major mode setting systems know how to set the mode".  But if the major mode is being set manually, then that idea won't work.

Comment: See function **`set-auto-mode`**. Maybe advise it. It is, AFAIK, the place where the major mode for a buffer is determined.